# Denominators of harmonic numbers: asymptotic behaviour.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, harmonic-numbers

About the sequence $d_n$ of the denominators of harmonic numbers, I know these facts:

- It is unbounded, since $p\mid d_p$ for any prime $p$.
- It contains only one $1$.

What more is known? Specially, is it true (as intuition suggests) that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n=\infty$$
? If not, is it known the inferior limit?

Answer (score 2):

The denominator $d_n$ is divisible by every prime $p$ satisfying $p\leq n<2p$ (only one term in the sum $H_n$ has denominator divisible by $p$). Bertrand's Postulate implies such a prime exists if $n \geq 2$, so $d_n\geq n/2 \to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Prime Number Theorem, it is possible to prove that $\log d_n \sim n$, as $n \to +\infty$. See Section 5 of [1] for a sketch proof.

[1] *D. W. Boyd, A p-adic Study of the Partial Sums of the Harmonic series, Experiment. Math. 3 (1994), 287-302.* https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1048515811